# Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO MediaTrackInactive(MediaTrackInactiveID, PrimaryCategoryID, Title, Source, AnchorName, ProducedBy, CoverageID, Content, AudioLength, IsLead, CreationTime, UploadTime, StoryTypeID, IsPending)  
VALUES(103257 , '10', 'How does the US make the case for its interests in Ukraine?', 'NewsHour, PBS NewsHour, News', '1', 'Reporting from the Aspen Ideas Festival in Colorado, Hari Sreenivasan interviews the former American Ambassador to Russia, Michael McFaul, in a conversation focused on the crisis in Ukraine and its impact on U.S.-Russian relations.', '365', '', 1404602224000, 1404689273287, 2, 0)
```

While trying to execute the above query the following error is coming 
**Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**
I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong
Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are providing less values than you have mentioned.

You have mentioned 14 column names and you are providing values for only 12 columns.

Comment: No it is right.

Shree.Pat , plz recheck the values, the values are going wrong as there is some missing inverted comma.

Comment: OK, apologies. I didn't see that `PBS Newshour,PBS Newshourt, Rivet` was a single string.

Comment: The source is corresponding to 'PBS NewsHour, PBS NewsHour, Rivet'

I Think inverted comma is missing which leads to 12 values instead of 14

Comment: Why can't MySQL ignore the columns we did not specify idk. smh.

Answer (score 6):

You have specified more columns than values. I guess some `'` is missing.

Maybe here: `'PBS NewsHour, PBS NewsHour, Rivet',`