# ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW while inserting database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i got error ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW when inserting into database, i dont know what is wrong, here's the code please help.

```
apiRouter.post('/interim/inputbaru', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log('postnya', req.body)
        const jbtn = req.body.jabatan.join(', ')
        const nmpjbt =  req.body.nama.join(`', '`)
        console.log(jbtn, `'`+nmpjbt+`'`)
        const { surattugas, tanggal, ketua, periode, cabang } = req.body
        await pool.query(
            'INSERT INTO INTERIM (SURATTUGAS, TGL, KETUA, PERIODE, KDCBG, '+ jbtn +') VALUES (?)',
            [surattugas, tanggal, ketua, periode, cabang, `'`+nmpjbt+`'`]
        );
        res.end()
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.code);
        const ERRORS = {
            ER_DUP_ENTRY: 'Surat Tugas tidak boleh sama',
            ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: 'Data Harus dipilih',
            ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: 'Data tidak valid',
            ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: 'Database Terisi',
            ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: 'Tidak boleh ada Data yang kosong'
        }
        res.status(500).send({ errMessage: ERRORS[err.code] || 'Kesalahan Sistem' });
    }
    // res.json(rows)
})

while my req.body is
{
  surattugas: 'kjadbkamd',
  tanggal: '2021-07-28',
  jabatan: [ 'PSO', 'PSDJ' ],
  ketua: 'MUHAMMAD',
  periode: 'TW II',
  cabang: 4,
  nama: [ 'sasasas', 'sasasasas' ]
}
```

please spot where my code is wrong, thanks

Comment: You are passing just 1 parameter to to the insert statement, not 6.

Comment: the VALUES (?) state for this value [surattugas, tanggal, ketua, periode, cabang, `'`+nmpjbt+`'`] isnt it?

Comment: Nope, it is not. You need a parameter per value.

Answer (score 0):

The error stand for "Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". Apparently you are providing mode or less values than expected.

At first sight it appears the number of values you are providing in the query to be 6, but I notice some of the values you're providing are arrays. That could be an issue, try to provide some strings to see how it works.

Similar to:
[Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773064/error-er-wrong-value-count-on-row-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-ro)

Comment: isnt this means

const nmpjbt =  req.body.nama.join(`', '`)
 and 
`'`+nmpjbt+`'`
equals to
('sasasas', 'sasasasas') a string?